# Using python with a DLL with openmp not using all cores

Tags: python, c++, openmp

I am using python 3.8 with a computation DLL written in C++ and using openmp to use all CPU's cores.
When I bench the C++ code it uses all the CPU's cores. But when I compile it as a DLL and use it from python, it only uses 1 core, like if Python was limiting the library to only use 1 core.

Here is my library compilation lines if I am doing something wrong:

```
g++ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fopenmp -pthread -o "src\\Environnement.o" "..\\src\\Environnement.cpp" 
g++ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fopenmp -pthread -o "src\\LexicalAnalyser.o" "..\\src\\LexicalAnalyser.cpp"
g++ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fopenmp -pthread -o "src\\Fun.o" "..\\src\\Fun.cpp"
g++ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fopenmp -pthread -o "src\\lib.o" "..\\src\\lib.cpp"
g++ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fopenmp -pthread -o "src\\Status.o" "..\\src\\Status.cpp" 
g++ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fopenmp -pthread -o "src\\Lexem.o" "..\\src\\Lexem.cpp" 
g++ -shared -o libSyntaxicAnalyser.dll "src\\Environnement.o" "src\\Fun.o" "src\\Lexem.o" "src\\LexicalAnalyser.o" "src\\Status.o" "src\\Variable.o" "src\\lib.o" "D:\\Apps\\mingw\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\9.2.0\\libgomp.a" -pthread
```

But I am feeling like python GIL is also applying to the C++ lib and prevent it to use all the cpu's cores...
Does anyone has the answer ?

Thank you very much
Sam

Answer (score 0):

So after digging, I have found 2 things:

- GIL does not apply to the DLL if called using CDLL. (GIL applies to the dll if you use PyDLL: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ctypes.html#loading-shared-libraries)
- In my C++ linker command line, gomp lib was missing (-lgomp). Here is the correct command:
  `g++ -LD:/Apps/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0 -shared -o libSyntaxicAnalyser.dll "src\\Environnement.o" "src\\Fun.o" "src\\Lexem.o" "src\\LexicalAnalyser.o" "src\\Status.o" "src\\Variable.o" "src\\lib.o" "src\\main.o" -lgomp -pthread`

And now it works !

Cheers